# I am using struts 2.5.13 and tiles 3.0 but got error missing required attribute "var"

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

I got error in this tag every where in jsp when i migrate my struts(2.0 to 2.5.13 ) and tiles (2.0 to 3.0)version

```
<s:set name="documents"  value="%{documents}"></s:set>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Read the migration guide - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite as below: (and any more? replace all with a RegEx replace)

```
<s:set var="documents"  value="%{documents}"></s:set>
```

See [Struts 2.3 to 2.5 migration](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html#Struts2.3to2.5migration-Tagsattributes)

Comment: so maybe it is for another tag in same or another jsp.

Comment: i have so many jsp but in each jsp this error is occur for <s.set > tag ..

Comment: "replace all with a RegEx replace" I said.